# Regarding VPN connectivity on mac

Tags: mac, vpn

I was using a VPN on my windows system and it was working just fine. I still have all the requirements.

But the issue now is, that I want to set up the same VPN connection for my Mac system. But I am unable to figure out why is it not working. Can someone help me out with this please.

I have the following information:

VPN Client Information

```
Host
Username
Password
```

Machine name

Another username and password to connect to the machine

Comment: This is not nearly enough information to connect to a VPN on any system. Please provide full information what kind of VPN, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what type of VPN you're connecting to? The two most popular are PPTP and L2TP. If you're selecting the wrong one then it won't connect.

A good hint is that if you need to enter two things to authenticate yourself (a password + shared key or password + certificate), then you're probably trying to connect to a L2TP VPN. If not, it's likely a PPTP.

In the case of a PPTP VPN, encryption strength can be an issue. VPN servers can be set to ignore clients that don't connect with some minimum strength of encryption. If you're using PPTP, try changing the Encryption setting to "Maximum (128 bit only)" in the Network Preferences entry for the VPN and see if that helps.